# Javaで作成したeventのhangoutLinkが取得できない時がある

Tags: java, playframework, google-calendar-api

Javaアプリで、Calendar API v3(v3-rev260-1.23.0)を利用して、Eventをinsertしています。
insert時に、attendeesパラメータでカレンダーユーザをゲスト登録しています。

しかし、レスポンスのEventからhangoutLinkが取得できない時があります。
0.002%の確率で取得できておりませんでした。

しかし、hangoutLinkが取得できない時でも、Googleカレンダーのイベントを参照すると、hangoutLinkは設定されています。
Event作成から実際にhangoutLinkが生成されるまで、タイムラグがあるのでしょうか。

どのような場合に、レスポンスEventからhangoutLinkが取得できないか、ご教授ください。
また、レスポンスからhangoutLinkが必ず取得できる方法がありましたら、ご教授ください。

なお、2020/09/01からは100%の確率で取得できておらず、Meet URLも追加されておりません。
Google Meetの設定が変更されたのでしょうか。

sampleコード

```
com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar service = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
        httpTransport, JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
Event event = new Event();
event.setSummary("タイトル");
event.setDescription("詳細");
DateTime start = new DateTime(開始時間, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
event.setStart(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(start));
DateTime end = new DateTime(終了時間, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
event.setEnd(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(end));
event.setGuestsCanModify(true);

java.util.List<EventAttendee> eAttendees = Lists.newArrayList();
EventAttendee eAttendee = new EventAttendee();
eAttendee.setEmail("testtest@example.com");
eAttendees.add(eAttendee);
event.setAttendees(eAttendees);

Event result = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
String meetURL = result.getHangoutLink();　　// ★←meetURLがnullの場合がある
```

Answer (score 1):

2020/09/01から取得できなくなったhangoutLinkについては、以下の対応で自己解決しました。
Calendar API v3のバージョンを、v3-rev260-1.23.0からv3-rev411-1.25.0へアップデートし、
insertイベントにCreateConferenceRequestをセットする処理を追加したところ、hangoutLinkが取得できるようになりました。